# Array index is out of bounds in Cloud Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Concerts
WHERE (ARRAY_LENGTH(TicketPrices) > 0 AND TicketPrices[OFFSET(0)] IS NOT NULL);
```

and I got:

```
ERROR: OUT_OF_RANGE: Array index 0 is out of bounds.
```

Why is the 2nd part being evaluated even when the first part is not true? How do I check if the array has one element with certain value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, SQL doesn't make any guarantees about evaluation order (unlike languages like C++ that offer short-circuit evaluation). The engine is free to evaluate the right-side of the AND before evaluating the left-side. You can [use](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/functions-and-operators#conditional-expressions) the `IF(cond,then-clause,else-clause)` to force a particular evaluation order.

Rewritten this way, your query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Concerts
WHERE IF(ARRAY_LENGTH(TicketPrices) > 0, TicketPrices[OFFSET(0)] IS NOT NULL, FALSE);
```